# How do i make React Datepicker states independent when the same DatePicker component is iterated many in a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, react-datepicker

I have a component that adds dynamically new fields in a list by a click of a button, then when all fields are filled it is populated to an array of objects 
 in this format

```
"prices": [
    {
        "from": "2019-01-01",
        "to": "2019-06-30",
        "price": 1560
    },
    {
        "from": "2019-07-01",
        "to": "2019-09-30",
        "price": 2010
    },
    {
        "from": "2019-10-01",
        "to": "2019-12-31",
        "price": 2010
    }
],
```

But the problem is when i add a another section which are DatePicker fields, it is already prefilled with the previous state of the date, a new set of fields need to be empty at all times until a value is put, what happens in the background does not reflect on the User Interface

here is a picture of the two sections and the second section is already prefilled with this.state.startDate and this.state.endDate,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Zuf.jpg

```
  import React, { Component} from 'react';

  import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

  import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

  class Brand extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        prices: [{ from: null, to: null, price: 0}]
    }

    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    this.handleRemovee = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePrices = this.handleChangePrices.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeStart = this.handleChangeStart.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeEnd = this.handleChangeEnd.bind(this);




}

handleChange = (value, name) => {

    this.setState(this.state[name] = value);

};

handleChangeStart(startDate){
    this.setState({startDate});
    console.log(this.state.startDate);
}

handleChangeEnd(endDate){
    this.setState({endDate});
    console.log(this.state.endDate);


}


handleChangePrices(i, e) {

    const prices = [...this.state.prices];
    prices[i].price = e.target.value;
    prices[i].from = this.state.startDate;
    prices[i].to = this.state.endDate;

    this.setState({ prices });
    console.log(this.state.prices);
    const {price, from, to} = this.state.prices;
    console.log(from);

    if(from === undefined){
        console.log("this is a mistake");
    }


}

handleAdd() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        prices: [...prevState.prices, { from: null, to:null, 
 price: 
        null }]
      }));

}

handleRemove(i) {
    const prices = [...this.state.prices];
    prices.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ prices });


}
handleSubmit(e) {

    alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.prices.join(", 
   "));
    console.log(this.state.prices);
  }
  render() {

    {
        const items = this.state.prices.map((el, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <div className="field-inputs__wrapper">
                    <div className="field-inputs__label">
                        {/* <div className="but-ons-brand">
                            <span>
                                <a onClick={() => 
this.handleRemove(i)} className="btn  btn-year btn-font" > Delete 
 Year</a>
                            </span>
                        </div> */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="field-inputs__form-input 
  date">
                        <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                            <div className="date-picker"> From 
  Date
                    </div>
                            <div className="date- 
picker__individual">

                                <DatePicker
                                    selected= 
{this.state.startDate}
                                    selectsStart
                                    startDate= 
{this.state.startDate}
                                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                                    onChange= 
{this.handleChangeStart}

                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                            <div className="date-picker">To Date
                    </div>
                            <div className="date- 
 picker__individual">

                                <DatePicker
                                    selected={this.state.endDate}
                                    selectsEnd
                                    startDate= 
 {this.state.startDate}
                                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                                    onChange= 
  {this.handleChangeEnd}
                                    minDate={this.state.startDate}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                            <div className="date- 
    picker__individual">
                                <label className="label-unique 
    band-price"> USD</label>
                                <input type="number" min="1" 
    placeholder="0" name="price" value={this.state.price} 
    onChange={e => this.handleChangePrices(i, e)} 
    className="input-band-price mb-3" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                            <div className="date- 
    picker__individual">
                                <div className="but-ons-brand">
                                    <span>
                                        <a onClick={() => 
    this.handleRemove(i)} className="btn btn-danger btn-font" > 
    Delete Band</a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        ));
        return (
            <>
            <form>
                {items}
                <div className="field-inputs__wrapper border-up- 
  year">
                    <div className="field-inputs__label">
                    </div>
                    <div className="field-inputs__form-input 
  date">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="field-inputs__wrapper">
                    <div className="field-inputs__label">
                    </div>
                    <div className="field-inputs__form-input 
  date">
                        <div className="but-ons-brand">
                            <span>
                                <a onClick={() => 
   this.handleAdd()} className="btn btn-success btn-font" > Add 
    Pricing Band</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="field-inputs__wrapper border-up- 
      year">
                    <div className="field-inputs__label">
                        <div className="but-ons-brand">
                            <span>
                                <a onClick={() => 
             this.handleSubmit()} className="btn btn-green btn- 
          font" > Add Year</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field-inputs__form-input 
           date">

                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </>
        )
    }

}
 }



  export default Brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a simple fix just used the index 'i' parameter for all my expected values to make them unique for each instance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ErrorLabels } from '../ErrorLabels';
import { FormInput } from 'shards-react';

class Brand extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prices: [{ from: null, to: null, price: "" }],
      disabled: true
    }

    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePrices = this.handleChangePrices.bind(this);
    this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);

  }

  handleDateChange(dateName, dateValue, index) {
    if (this.state.prices[index].price === 0) {
      console.log("error on prices")
    }

    if (dateName === 'startDateTime') {
      this.state.prices[index].from = dateValue;
      this.setState({ startDate: dateValue });
      return;
    }
    this.state.prices[index].to = dateValue;
    this.setState({ endDate: dateValue });
    this.props.setPrices(this.state.prices);

  }

  handleChangePrices(i, e) {
    const prices = [...this.state.prices];
    prices[i].price = e.target.value;
    prices[i].from = this.state.startDate;
    prices[i].to = this.state.endDate;

    this.setState({ prices });
    this.props.setPrices(this.state.prices);
  }

  handleAdd() {
    if (this.state.prices.length <= 2) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        prices: [...prevState.prices, { from: null, to: null, price: null }]
      }));

    }

    return;



  }

  handleRemove(i) {
    const prices = [...this.state.prices];
    prices.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ prices: prices });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    this.props.setPrices(this.state.prices);
  }
  render() {
    {
      const items = this.state.prices.map(( i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <div className="field-inputs__wrapper">
            <div className="field-inputs__label">
            </div>
            <div className="field-inputs__form-input date">
              <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                <div className="date-picker"> From Date
                        </div>
                <div className="date-picker__individual">

                  <DatePicker
                    id="start-date-time"
                    name="startDateTime"
                    placeholderText="-"
                    className="form-control"
                    showDisabledMonthNavigation
                    selected={this.state.prices[i].from || null}
                    selectsStart
                    startDate={this.state.startDate}
                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                    onChange={date => this.handleDateChange('startDateTime', date, i)}
                    autosuggest="off"

                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                <div className="date-picker">To Date
                        </div>
                <div className="date-picker__individual">

                  <DatePicker
                    id="end-date-time"
                    name="endDateTime"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholderText="-"
                    showDisabledMonthNavigation
                    selected={this.state.prices[i].to || null}
                    selectsEnd
                    startDate={this.state.prices[i].from || null}
                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                    onChange={date => this.handleDateChange('endDateTime', date, i)}
                    minDate={this.state.startDate}
                    autosuggest="off"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                <div className="date-picker__individual">
                  <label className="label-unique band-price"> USD</label>

                  <ErrorLabels errors={this.props.errors} name="price" />
                  <FormInput type="number" min="0" placeholder="0" name="price" value={this.state.price} onChange={e => this.handleChangePrices(i, e)} className="input-band-price mb-3" required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="date-picker-wrapper">
                <div className="date-picker__individual">
                  <div className="but-ons-brand-delete">
                    <span>
                      <div onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)} className="btn btn-danger btn-font" > Delete Band</div>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      ));
      return (
        <>
          <div className="field-inputs__wrapper">
            <div className="field-inputs__label">
            </div>
            <div className="field-inputs__form-input date">

            </div>
          </div>

          {items}
          <div className="field-inputs__wrapper">
            <div className="field-inputs__label">
            </div>
            <div className="field-inputs__form-input date">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="field-inputs__wrapper">
            <div className="field-inputs__label">
            </div>
            <div className="field-inputs__form-input date">
              <div className="button-brand">
                <span>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleAdd()} className="btn btn-success btn-font" > Add Pricing Band</div>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )
    }

  }
}




const mapStateToProps = ({ posts }) => {
  const { errors } = posts;

  return {
    errors,
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Brand);
```